# My firebase storage is not private despite the rules being set for private

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

Background: I'm building a React Native iOS app which will involve uploading images and being able to access them from within the app (but not publicly).

In my rules for Firebase storage, I have the following:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

As I understand this, only an authorized Firebase user should be able to access the files. However, I've uploaded an image which I can access in any browser:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/boiling-heat-632.appspot.com/o/download.jpeg?alt=media&token=7a8708c5-3dda-4088-b456-6dffd6ffc006

Is there something wrong with my security rules? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The link you have provided is a public URL that will/can be generated for all Firebase storage objects. It is called a download URL. It is considered to be unguessable, so you shouldn't have to worry about it being there. You will probably find that if you try and access your storage object via the Firebase storage framework (with the object path) you will not be allowed to do so.

Hope this answers your question

*Update*:
For further info see this [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aw86jf8b7PY)

Comment: Thank you so much Chris for the clear answer. Once I set up user login via Firebase in my app, I'll be able to report back on this.